# getting a plugin to trigger on a live/on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a link that pulls in some new content via ajax, and in each peace of content there is a link that triggers the jQuery plugin colorbox. The colorbox triggers fine, when I click the trigger on original page load, however once I have loaded in some new content colorbox will no longer trigger, here is my jquery,

```
$(".magnify").on("click", function(e) {
        $(this).colorbox({ 
            inline:true, 
            opacity: 0.9,
            innerWidth: 800,
            innerHeight:700
        });
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
```

Here is my HTML

```
   <a href="#inline_content" class="magnify inline"><img src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>/_/images/magnify.png" alt="Magnify" />
                                    <span class="play">Watch the Logic+ being manufactured at our plant in Hull</span>
                                    </a>

<div style="display:none">
                                    <div id="inline_content">
                                        <span class="zoomImage" id="ex1">
                                            <img src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/_/images/combi-inside-large.jpg" width="329" height="606"/>
                                        </span>                 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

How can I make colorbox work with my ajax requests?

Comment: Well could you post your ajax code please?